# pinpoint the position of devices

Tags: trigonometry, logic

[image: 3 devices that emit a signal and can know its distance using a 4º device]

My question is I know the distances d1, d2 and d3, thats the only information I have access to, but am build a android app where I need to indicate the positions of where the devices that are represent by the points in the corners of the triangle to position of point in the center of the tringle.

So was think in getting the sizes of the triangle(of the triangle lines)  using a^2 +  b^2 = c^2 and from there get the angules between the d1,d2 and d3 lines and from there being able to pinpoint more or less the devices positions to the device at the center, is this the way to go or is there a easier way?

Comment: How do you want to "pinpoint"?

Comment: by getting the angule between the lines in grey

Comment: DO you have any other information besides $d_1, d_2$ and $d_3$?

Comment: only have that information, but am starting to look for triangulation it may simplify the process

Comment: Do you know the distance between the end points (not the center) of $d_1$, $d_2$, $d_3$?

Comment: yes since the those point are devices where will possible to control the distances to each other

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha_{12}$ be the angle between $d_1$ and $d_2$ and $d$, the distance between end points of $d_1$ and $d_2$. Then use [law of cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines):
$$\cos\alpha_{12}=\frac{d_1^2+d_2^2-d^2}{2d_1d_2}$$
Similarly work out the rest of the angles.